# Is there any other means to achieve scroll position state without using indexed stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, screen

I am currently using **IndexedStack** in a project, and the reason I decided to go with it is that:
If I want to change tabs or even navigate to other parts of the app from a screen with a scrollable widget, when I switch/come back to the screen, the screen will still maintain the scroll position it was.

What I noticed and don't like is how all the screens attached to IndexedStack as children are initialized, even before accessing them.

BottomNavigationBar does a better in handling screens.

What is the way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass a ScrollController to your scrollable widget, and then call this controller to scroll to the top when you come back or right before you come back.